# Postorder traversal of binary tree with recursive data type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function for a post-order traversal of a recursive data type that creates an binary tree where the examples could create as many child leafs as possible. I've tried to set the nodes to left:root:right but the error doesn't recognize them - however, it would recognize (y:ys). It also recognizes root as an Int no matter if I use () or [] or nothing around it. What am I missing?

This is the data type and some easy examples to test it with:

```
data BiTree a = L a
            | N [BiTree a]

ex1 :: BiTree Int
ex1 = N [(L 1),(L 1),(L 3)]

ex2 :: BiTree Int
ex2 = N [(L 1),(N[(L 2),(L 3)]),(L 4)]
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
postord :: BiTree a -> [Int]
postord (L x)                  = [x]
postord (N (left:root:right))  = postord (N right) ++ postord (N left) ++ [root]
```

Here's the error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `BiTree a'
* In the expression: root
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely `[root]'
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely
    `postord (N left) ++ [root]'
* Relevant bindings include
    right :: [BiTree a] (bound at try.hs:21:23)
    root :: BiTree a (bound at try.hs:21:18)
    left :: BiTree a (bound at try.hs:21:13)
    postord :: BiTree a -> [Int] (bound at try.hs:20:1)
|
21 | postord (N (left:root:right)) = postord (N right) ++ postord (N left) ++ [root]
|                                                         ^^^^
```

I don't understand why left:right:root won't bind, and why recalling postord in the list with appends won't compile a list of every node within the right node, left node, and root as it is.

Comment: It seems to me that you're mixing up a true binary tree (which would have a rather different-looking `data` declaration) with your version where you pass a list of subtrees. (To be a true binary tree that list would only ever have 2 elements, but this type doesn't enforce that, and you've given an example with 3.)

Comment: A postorder traversal is where you process all of the children of the branch, and then process the value in the branch. You're not storing values in the branches though, only in the leaves, so the idea of a postorder or preorder traversal is meaningless with this structure. What the code you wrote would actually do (if written properly) is process the third child, fourth child, etc on to the last child, then the first child, then the second child, in that order. I doubt that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`N` doesn't have specific left and right children, and it certainly doesn't have any distinguished root value; it *just* has an arbitrary list of children.

You `BiTree` only stores values in the leaves. The only thing to do with an `N` value is map `postord` on to each child, and concatenate the results into a single list. (As such, there's no real difference between the pre-, in-, and post-order traversals.)

```
postord :: BiTree a -> [a]
postord (L x)         = [x]
postord (N children)  = concatMap postord children
```

Now, if you had a type that *did* store values in the internal nodes, your type might look like

```
data BiTree a = L a | N a [BiTree a]
```

Then your post-order traversal would have to account for the value stored in an internal node, similar to your previous attempt.

```
postord :: BiTree a -> [a]
postord (L x) = [x]
postord (N v children) = concatMap postord children ++ [v]
```

Appending a single value to a longer list isn't ideal, but that's a problem for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood your question, but what about this:

```hs
postord :: BiTree a -> [a]
postord (L x) = [x]
postord (N cs) = concatMap postord cs
```

Comment: What does <$> mean? Could I substitute something else for it? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Francis `<$>` is the infix alias of `fmap`. It's use is equivalent to `fmap postord right`

Comment: Is there any way I can write that as a helper function instead using <$>? It's too advanced for me and I'm wondering if I can show the way it's working instead of calling <$> of fmap?

Comment: @Francis Are you familiar with `map`? For lists, `fmap = map`

Comment: I aligned with respect to @chepner's answer.